# Why are variables - marked <<<<<< undefined

Tags: c++, visual-studio, wxwidgets

I am new to C++ and wxWidgets and trying to follow a basic example which appears to run with the exception of the `OnButtonClicked` marked by <<<<<<<

The variables are undefined at the Build stage (if I comment out both lines the code will run)

Is there something wrong with the definition of the variable m_list1 and m_txt1?

```
    //===================cMain.h ===========
#pragma once    //see 22:450
#include "wx/wx.h"

class cMain : public wxFrame
{
public:
    cMain();
    ~cMain();
public:
    wxButton *m_btn1 = nullptr;  //25:48
    wxTextCtrl *m_txt1 = nullptr;
    wxListBox *m_list1 = nullptr;

    void OnButtonClicked(wxCommandEvent &evt);  //27:30
    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();  // 27:34
};
    //===================cMain.cpp ===========
#include "cMain.h"

wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(cMain,wxFrame)  // 28:00
    //EVT_BUTTON(10001,OnButtonClicked) //28:33
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()

cMain::cMain() : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, "Peter's First WxWidget Code ",wxPoint(30,30),wxSize(800,600))
{
    m_btn1 = new wxButton(this, 10001, "Click Me", wxPoint(10, 10), wxSize(150, 50));   //28:36
    m_txt1=new wxTextCtrl(this, wxID_ANY, "", wxPoint(10, 70), wxSize(300, 30));
    m_list1=new wxListBox(this, wxID_ANY,  wxPoint(10, 110), wxSize(300,300));
}


cMain::~cMain()
{
}

void OnButtonClicked(wxCommandEvent &evt)
{
    //m_list1->AppendString(m_txt1->GetValue());        //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    m_list1->AppendString("ONE");                       //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    evt.Skip();     //29.24
}

    //===================cApp.h ===========
#pragma once                            //24:09

#include "wx/wx.h"
#include "cMain.h"

class cApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    cApp();
    ~cApp();

private:
    cMain* m_frame1 = nullptr;

public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};
    //===================cApp.cpp ===========

#include "cApp.h"          // 24:19
wxIMPLEMENT_APP(cApp);
cApp::cApp()
{
}

cApp::~cApp()
{
}
bool cApp::OnInit()
{
    m_frame1 = new cMain();
    m_frame1->Show();
    return true;
}
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Please copy paste error message compiler/linker reports! Note that this `<<<<<` in a title is only a noise, so think about better title.

Comment: My C++ is **really** rusty, but it doesn't look like `OnButtonClicked` is a member of the class, so it doesn't have freestanding access to the class public properties. You'd need an instance (or to make `OnButtonClicked` a member of the class by putting `cMain::` in front of the name).

Comment: Typo, it should be: `void cMain::OnButtonClicked(wxCommandEvent &evt)`

Comment: Outside the class definition, member function names need to be prefixed with the class name and `::` (scope) operator.  For example, when defining `void OnButtonClicked(wxCommandEvent &evt)`  outside the class definition, it needs to be `void cMain::OnButtonClicked(wxCommandEvent &evt)`.        [And, instead of guessing, try reading a basic text which will tell you these things].

Comment: @PeterWilliams, on top what everybody else said - `EVT_BUTTON(10001,OnButtonClicked)` should really be `EVT_BUTTON(10001,cMain::OnButtonClicked)`.

Comment: @Igor you need an `&` to take the address of the member function.

Comment: @JDługosz, no, you don't. Look at the `minimal` sample provided with wxWidgets.

Comment: @Igor https://godbolt.org/z/ezKh1YYYf  The macro must add the `&`.  Gotta love `#define`s that take syntax that's not normal C++ code!

Comment: W@JDługosz, please check https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/samples/minimal/minimal.cpp.It is very normal C++ code that compiles with every known C++ compiler and executes on all 3 major platforms. You just not familiar with the syntax. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

`void OnButtonClicked(wxCommandEvent &evt)` should have been
`void cMain::OnButtonClicked(wxCommandEvent &evt)`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `m_list1` is not found as a valid variable name?

`void OnButtonClicked(wxCommandEvent &evt)` is a stand-alone function.  It is not part of any class.

The only `m_list1` I see is a member of `cMain`.  So, it is not in the scope of the function.  It would be a member variable if you were writing a *member function* of that class, but you're writing a global (free) function.

You don't have any pointer to any instance of any of the classes you define in your source, so you can't get there from here.

Perhaps you want `OnButtonClick` to be a member of `cMain`.  I don't know this framework, but I see you're not registering the function pointer to a callback; if the framework just knows to call a **member** of that name, then your mistake was simply not making this function a member of the class.

Comment: Many thanks for the comments.  I had copied the code from a Youtube video not thinking the solution would be quite so flawed.  I'll make some changes and sorry about use of the less than sign to highlight an area of concern.    Thanks again for all comments